# Error- Collection<Object> cannot be converted to List<Class>

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stored-procedures

I am learning to use stored procedure in java. Earlier I used JDBC Template and I was able to fetch values from database.
Now I have an error :  Collection Object cannot be converted to List Class

**Is there any way I can convert Collection(Object) to List(Class)?**

is my model class

My Stored Procedure Class

```
public class ListRegistration extends StoredProcedure {
     @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private static final String SCHEMA_NAME = "ehr";
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "ehr.usp_ListRegistration";

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public ListRegistration(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("rs", new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Patient.class)));
       declareParameter(new SqlParameter("LimitRows", Types.INTEGER));
        compile();
    }
public List<Patient> spExecute(Integer LimitRows)
{

  Map<String, Object> registrationResult=new HashMap<String,Object>();
     registrationResult = super.execute(LimitRows);

  List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>;
 patientList = registrationResult.values();
      return patientList;
}
```

}

```
List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>;
     patientList = registrationResult.values();
```

This is where I get the error.

In my implementaion class I have

```
   public List<Patient> getPatient() {
    System.out.println("============================ Will Fetch Values ");
    List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
     int t=100;
      patientList=listRegistration.spExecute(100);
      return patientList;
    }
```

Comment: could you please post your StoredProcedure class

Comment: I have given the stored procedure class above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values()` returns a Set, not a List.

What you can do though is:

```
 List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList(registrationResults.values());
```

This will create a new list and fill it with the returned keys.

Why do you actually need to do this though? If you just work with `values` as a `Collection` or `Set` the code will be more efficient.